# Regression tables made with esttab in Stata have columns with different widths, using LyX

Tags: tables, lyx

I am relatively new to LyX and I am trying to output regression results into TeX code, and then insert the resulting tables in a LyX document.
The command I use to create the table is:

```
reg y1 x1, vce(cluster COD) // specification without controls
eststo C1

reg y1 x1 x2, vce(cluster COD) // specification with controls 
eststo C2 

reg y2 x1, vce(cluster COD) // specification without controls
eststo C3

reg y2 x1 x2, vce(cluster COD) // specification with controls 
eststo C4

esttab C1 C2 C3 C4 using `test_tex', se(%3.2f) b(2) label booktabs indicate(controls=x2) ///
star(* 0.1 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) nonotes ///
addnotes("\specialcell{Standard errors corrected for heteroskedasticity at school level between brackets\\  \textit{*p < 0.10, ** p < 0.51, *** p < 0.01}}") ///
nomtitles mgroups("mat" "com", pattern(1 0 1 0) prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span}))  ///
drop(_cons) replace
```

Then I just input a Child Document into my main LyX file (see output below)
The table is automatically sized because of the longer note at the bottom, and as a result the table is larger than it would be automatically, so the fourth column is larger than the rest. I'd like all columns to have the same width (to be proportionally sized within the table).

Here is the LateX code outputed by the Stata command:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{mat}                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{com}                    \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule
x1                  &        0.19\sym{*}  &        0.14\sym{**} &        0.12         &        0.10         \\
                    &      (0.10)         &      (0.07)         &      (0.08)         &      (0.06)         \\
\addlinespace
controls            &          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        2401         &        2401         &        2401         &        2401         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \specialcell{Standard errors corrected for heteroskedasticity at school level between brackets\\  \textit{*p < 0.10, ** p < 0.51, *** p < 0.01}}}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

And a screenshot of the result when the previous LaTeX code is inserted in a LyX document with the appropriate preamble (found here http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/ )
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/24449)! As you mentioned you are using the program Stata. Not everyone is using it and it is not easily obtained (not open source). It would help if you added the TeX code that you generated by Stata to your question. Shorten the TeX code as much as possible to a table of minimal length such that the problem still occurs (see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1098/24449) or [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/24449)). A screenshot is not necessary if the problem can be reproduced...

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response, I thought I'd be notified by email and just checked in here now. Just edited my question to add the LaTeX code, and was also able to add the screenshot of the output. Thanks all for your help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you did not follow the [Jörg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11984/jorg) instructions completely.

First make sure that you add Jörg's preamble into your document preamble (in LyX: Document > Settings > Latex-Preamble):

```
% Packages for tables
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\usepackage{threeparttablex}% For Notes below table

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}} % Thanks to Joseph Wright & David Carlisle

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        }   

% Character substitution that prints brackets and the minus symbol in text mode. Thanks to David Carlisle
\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl[\xxxr]\xxxl(\xxxr)\yyy}


% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
% The new approach using threeparttables to generate notes that are the exact width of the table.
\newcommand{\Figtext}[1]{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \hspace{6pt}
    \hangindent=1.75em
    #1
    \end{tablenotes}
    }
\newcommand{\Fignote}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Figsource}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Starnote}{\Figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}% Add significance note with \starnote
```

You said you did that but Jörg made some refinements in his [follow-up](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/08/latex-and-stata-integration-solving-some-problems/) [posts](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/08/latex-stata-design/). I took this from his [sample document](https://www.jwe.cc/download/456/). Note that I included the `threeparttablex` package instead of `threeparttable`, since the former also supports `longtable` (for tables spanning more than one page, should you need that). For this example, however, this does not matter.

e-birk is right that not everyone has access to Stata, but for those that do, it helps to add a MWE that makes use of the example datasets installed with Stata (`help sysuse`). So I adjusted your example like this:

```
sysuse auto
regress mpg weight length foreign, robust // specification with 'foreign' 
eststo C1
regress mpg weight length, robust // specification without 'foreign'
eststo C2 
regress price weight length foreign, robust // specification with 'foreign'
eststo C3
regress price weight length, robust // specification without 'foreign'
eststo C4
```

Now export the table from Stata as a fragment and without the table notes (we add these later into the LaTeX/LyX document). The right `esttab` command should be something like this:

```
esttab C1 C2 C3 C4 using test_tex, booktabs fragment replace ///
se(%3.2f) b(3) label  indicate(Controls=foreign) ///
star(* 0.1 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) nonotes nomtitles drop(_cons) ///
mgroups("mpg" "weight", pattern(1 0 1 0) ///
prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span}))
```

Note that I added the fragment option. I also reformated the command a little. This way you can just add `, ///` before `using` in the first line to test your table in Stata first (e.g. to see whether labels are correct, etc.).

Finally, include the table in LyX with this (adjust accordingly):

```
\begin{table}\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table with Better Notes and Better Symbols}
    \estauto{test_tex}{4}{c}
    \Figtext{Some basic text about the table.}
    \Fignote{Standard errors corrected for heteroskedasticity in brackets.  \\
    \textit{* p < 0.10, **  p < 0.5, *** p < 0.01}}
    \Figsource{auto.dta (Stata example dataset)}
    % \Starnote 
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

You can insert this into your LyX document with Evil Red Text (Insert > Tex-Code) or use a .tex document and insert that as a file into your document.

I added the p-value note directly, but you could also use the `\Starnote` command (useful if you have multiple tables with the same p-symbols). Adjust the p-values on the last line of the preamble accordingly.

I also used the center alignment `{c}` in `\estauto{test_tex}{4}{c}` instead of the decimal alignment `{S}`, since the latter seems to choke on the Controls row. I am not very familiar with the `siunitx` package, so I might be wrong here or there might be an easy fix.

Obviously, this is mostly Jörg's code, he deserves the credit.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This solves the problem. I adapted your instructions a little, and now my tables look perfect.

Comment: @Ines: Glad I could help. If you like my answer, please accept it by clicking the tick/checkmark symbol on the left.

Comment: Thanks for spreading my instructions! Do you mind if I use your Stata example to improve the instruction on my homepage? Also, have you actually tried to produce a longtable (with `threeparttablex`)? I tried it once with the `longtable` package, but that did not work.

Comment: The issue with `siunitx` is probably font related: You use my "advanced" example with character substitution, i.e. math-minusses are properly formatted. In the example I use `libertine`, so if you are using another font that might cause problems. You could try to my "simpler" example, which essentially comments `\textsymbols` in the definition of the `\estauto` and `\estwide` commands. Then `siunitx` should work.

Comment: @Jörg: Sure you can use the Stata example. I have successfully produced longtables with `threeparttablex' and `longtable' before, but those did not include any of your adjustments. That is on my todo someday list. Thanks for straightening the `siunitx' issue out.