# stata mlogit margins margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome()) export to LaTeX table

Tags: tables

I am estimating a multinomial logistic regression model in STATA

```
mlogit Y X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
```

Then using a loop I get the marginal effects

```
est store m
forval i = 0/5 {
est res m
margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome(`i')) post
est store m`i'
}
estout m0 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
```

And I want to add these results everytime along with the coefficients of the corresponding outcome
of the mlogit using the estadd command and then
store them and export them in tex using esttab.

I would normally write (to export the .tex table)

```
<fit model>
estadd margins, dydx(*)
estout, cells("b margins_b" "se(par) margins_se(par)")
est store A

esttabA using table1.tex replace f star(* 0.10 **0.05 ***0.001)
cells("b(fmt(3)star) margins_b(star)" "se fmt(3)par)")
stats(N r2_p chi2 p pr, fmt(0 3)
```

But this works only for margins, dydx(*) atmeans but these do not change for the different outcomes, where I want to get each time the coefficient and next to it the marginal effects

```
Outcome1   Coeff     Marginal Effect

Variable1  coeff11   margeff11  
Variable2  coeff12   margeff12  
Variable3  coeff13   margeff13  

Outcome2   Coeff     Marginal Effect  
Variable1  coeff21   margeff21  
Variable2  coeff22   margeff22  
Variable3  coeff23   margeff23
```

Can anyone help me do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Stata or estout problem than it is a LaTeX problem. There is a section on marginal effects after mlogit on the [estout website](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/advanced.html#advanced401), but honestly I do not really understand what it is doing and I suspect that it is calculating marginal effects at means instead of the average marginal effects that you want.

In any case you get more flexibility with the following example.

```
// load example data and fit model - this is from the mlogit help file
webuse sysdsn1
mlogit insure age male nonwhite i.site, rrr
est store m

// estimate average marginal effects
forval i = 1/3 {
est res m
margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome(`i')) post
est store m`i'
}

// export results per outcome in one table
esttab m m1 using mlogit_frag.tex, booktabs fragment replace ///
    equations(Out1 = 1:1) keep(Out1:) drop(?b.*) eqlabels(none) nonumber noobs ///
    mlabel("Coeff." "Marg.Eff.", lhs("Outcome 1")) 
esttab m m2 using mlogit_frag.tex, booktabs fragment append ///
    equations(Out2 = 2:1) keep(Out2:) drop(?b.*) eqlabels(none) nonumber noobs ///
    mlabel("Coeff." "Marg.Eff.", lhs("\midrule Outcome 2")) 
esttab m m3 using mlogit_frag.tex, booktabs fragment append ///
    equations(Out3 = 3:1) keep(Out3:) drop(?b.*) eqlabels(none) nonumber ///
    mlabel("Coeff." "Marg.Eff.", lhs("\midrule Outcome 3"))
```

I guess the estimation part is clear.

In the `esttab` part I match the model equations by outcome category (e.g. `equations(Out2 = 2:1)` means "Match equation 2 of the first model mentioned (i.e. `m`) with the first equation of the second model (i.e. `m2` - the marginal effects only have one equation) and call this equation `Out2` (or whatever)). I have to name the equation in order to be able to only keep this equation of model `m` (and drop the others). This is what `keep(Out3:)` does.

`drop(?b.*)` drops the reference categories. The other options should become clear from the `esttab`/`estout` help file.

After that inserting your table into your main document is relatively easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} % define p-value symbols from estout
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{A nice table caption \label{tab:yourlabel}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
            \toprule
            \input{mlogit_frag.tex}
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para]
            \footnotesize
            \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\) 

            Standard errors in parentheses.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I use `threeparttablex` so that the [tablenotes do not widen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97764/19662) the table but wrap beneath it. See the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) for details. The `[para]` option is explained in the [`threeparttable` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable).

In essence you just need everything in the `tabular` environment (or an equivalent), the `\def` line for the significance stars and possibly `booktabs`, though.